# Создание корневой файловой системы без получения прав суперпользователя в Linux

Tags: linux

Я на своем ПК под управлением Linux создаю корневую файловую систему для встроенной системы под управлением Linux. Ее архитектура не 386. (Microbalze). Она должна быть в 2-х вариантах: как файл образа(rootfs.img) с файловой системой Ext4, этот файл будет затем записан во flash на целевой встроенной системе, и как каталог, доступный по сети через NFS.
Вопрос: как назначить всем файлам этой корневой ФС владелцем root, не получая прав root на моем ПК, на котором я ее собираю?
В книге "Linux from scratch" предлагается делать это с помощью chroot, т.е. создать в отдельной папке мини-rootfs со всеми нужными программами(bash, gcc итд), сделать в нее chroot и затем работать в ней с правами суперпользователя. Но у этого варианта очевидные недостатки:
1. У меня уже все программы установлены, зачем их устанавливать по второму разу?
2. Файл rootfs.img принадлежит мне, но для его редактирования я должен зачем-то получать права root.
3. В конце концов, возможна ситуация, когда пользователю не разрешено получение root прав на его ПК.
Спасибо всем ответившим.

Comment: я дополнил свой ответ, добавив краткую информацию про *guestfish* и *virt-make-fs*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Вопрос: как назначить всем файлам этой корневой ФС владелцем root, не получая прав root на моем ПК, на котором я ее собираю?

## обновлённый вариант ответа

в уже собранном образе можно «похозяйничать» с помощью, например, программы *guestfish* из [пакета *libguestfs-tools*](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libguestfs-tools&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). для ускорения работы требуется, чтобы пользователь входил в группу *kvm* (это в *debian gnu/linux*, в других дистрибутивах она, возможно, будет называться иначе).

пример с файлом, содержащим `образ` файловой системы (знаком `>` в начале строки отмечены команды, выполняемые «внутри» псевдо-оболочки, которая запускается программой *guestfish*):

```
$ guestfish -a образ
> run
```

смотрим список файловых систем — там присутствует только одна, та, что находится внутри файла с образом, который указан с помощью опции `-a`):

```
> list-filesystems
/dev/sda: ext2
```

монтируем эту файловую систему в качестве корня:

```
> mount /dev/sda /
```

можно посмотреть файлы (здесь, для примера, в файловой системе присутствует только один `файл`):

```
> ls /
lost+found
файл
```

изменить принадлежнось можно встроенной командой *chown* (и пользователя и группу надо указывать в цифровом виде):

```
> chown 0 0 /файл
```

как я понял, рекурсивно эта команда, увы, не работает. так что если надо поменять принадлежность большого количества файлов, то придётся автоматизировать процесс. в `man guestfish` есть примеры, которые помогут в такой автоматизации.

завершить сеанс псевдо-оболочки можно либо командой `exit`, либо нажатием <kbd>ctrl+d</kbd>.

## про создание образа с помощью virt-make-fs

кстати, в уже упомянутом пакете *libguestfs-tools* есть программа *virt-make-fs*, с помощью которой можно создать образ с файловой системой из архива:

```
$ virt-make-fs архив.tar образ
```

ну а поместить в архив файлы с нужной принадлежностью можно, как обычно, с помощью *fakeroot*. например, находясь в каталоге, являющимся «корнем» создаваемой файловой системы:

```
$ fakeroot bash
$ chown -R пользователь:группа *
$ tar -cf архив.tar *
$ exit
```

если пользователь и группа — это root, то вызов `chown` может и не потребоваться, ведь «внутри» окружения, созданного программой *fakeroot* текущий пользователь выглядит «как бы *root*-ом», и принадлежащие ему файлы/каталоги выглядят «как бы принадлежащими *root*-у». см. вывод `$ ls -l`

## старый вариант ответа, про genext2fs

но можно для **самой** сборки образа воспользоваться, например, программой *genext2fs* (*ext2 filesystem generator for embedded systems*) из [одноимённого пакета](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=genext2fs&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

пример (всё выполняется от имени рядового пользователя):

1. создаём «корневой» каталог для нашей файловой системы, а в нём файл:

   ```
    $ mkdir корень; touch корень/файл
   ```
2. создаём образ с файловой системой *ext2* размером в 1024 блока, с подменой пользователя (опция `-U`):

   ```
    $ genext2fs -U -b 1024 -d корень образ
   ```

---

проверяем. тут уже (для монтирования) потребуются права суперпользователя:

```
$ mkdir точка.монтирования
$ sudo mount образ точка.монтирования
```

и видим, что созданный файл принадлежит пользователю *root*:

```
$ ls -l точка.монтирования
total 52
drwx------ 2 root root 52224 Sep 28 18:26 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Sep 28 18:11 файл
```

не забываем отмонтировать:

```
$ sudo umount точка.монтирования
```

---

p.s. в принципе, и для монтирования можно, в крайнем случае, обходиться без дополнительных прав, воспользовавшись программой *fuse-ext2* из [пакета *fuseext2*](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=genext2fs&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all):

```
$ fuse-ext2 образ точка.монтирования
```

программа выдаст много строчек с информацией, из которой в данном случае полезной является только уведомление о том, что файловая система смонтирована в режиме «только для чтения».

не забываем отмонтировать:

```
$ fusermount -u точка.монтирования
```

---

полезная информация:

- [Creating SD image without root privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10949169/4827341)
- [Mount an image file without root permission?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32008/110559)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Какие системы создания сборки пакетов Linux программ лучше всегда подходят для кросс платформенной сборки? Например , PKGBUILD от Arhlinux.

Comment: @Reffum, я думаю, «лучше всегда подходят» те, которые вам лучше известны.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ будет "никак". Все решения, которые можно придумать, либо хаки с целью получить-таки права рута на минуточку, либо просто через права рута.

А зачем такие странные ограничения?
Почему вы не можете на своём ПК побыть 10 секунд рутом?
Зачем этому файлу принадлежать руту?

Comment: Сам файл с образом rootfs.img принадлежит мне, и я не хочу чтобы его владельцем был root, я хочу, чтобы root был владельцем файлов в файловой системе, созданной в этом образе.

Comment: @Reffum, так измените владельца: `$ sudo chown владелец файл`

Comment: @Smithson, как оказалось, ответ «никак» — не совсем верен. см. мой ответ, в части про *guestfish*.

Comment: Я не понял вопроса, я не понял, что надо поменять владельца внутри образа.